Did the first stage of Vulcan-Centaur explode after separation?
Yesterday Vulcan Centaur launched for the second time to get certified for national security missions. The launch had a widely discussed anomaly with one of the solid rocket boosters. However there seems to have possibly been a second anomaly later in the launch during first stage separation.
The SRB anomaly occurred about thirty seconds into launch, and continued through SRB separation at about T+0:02:20. First stage separation occurred at about T+0:05:00. The possible anomaly that I am referring to occurred just after first stage separation, several minutes after the SRB anomaly.
During the first stage separation, ULA's livestream had already swapped to the animation, while the NSF livestream still had its cameras focused on the rocket. In their livestream, something that looked like an explosion was visible. However, I haven’t seen any mention of it, and most commentators were focusing on the earlier solid rocket issue. Was the apparent explosion after first stage separation a nominal event? Did the FTS trigger or maybe the first stage experience a RUD after separation?
Here is a clip of what appears to be an explosion

It may have been thrusters firing during and after separation, considering that this was above 100 km the plumes would be very large and this was a morning launch with great lighting of events at high altitude. Another possibility is that the ULA callouts were slightly behind (or their livestream delayed) and that it was the prestart on the RL10's which would start flowing LH2 and LOX through the engines prior to ignition which would immediately vaporize when they are dumped overboard.

Looks like thrusters to me too, you see similar sometimes on falcon 9 separations

I think it was clear that you were referring to a separate event not the SRB issue, but there seems to be some confusion about it so I edited the question to try and make it more clear what event you are referring to. Feel free to roll back if it's not what you meant.

@StevePemberton I looked at the edit and it seems good . I‘ll keep it

No, it didn't explode. According to ULA CEO Tory Bruno, other than the SRB issues, "the flight was nominal". Given that nominal means that everything went as expected, I think that means that there was no explosion on the first stage, even after separation.

weird, that's the same quote that was in David Hammen's downvoted and deleted answer, which also misspelled Tory Bruno's name

The question was about the main booster, not the SRB

@ErinAnne not only that but Starship is on the list of delete voters for that answer

@AlanBirtles I VTDed that because it was just talking about “wait for details” which doesn’t actually answer the question

@AlanBirtles You're right. Turns out the actual answer to the question was in the same article though:)

@ErinAnne Yeah, I realized the old one wasn't what the OP asked so I changed it to be an answer to the actual question. What's wrong with that? Fixed the Tony vs. Tory again

I'm not going to downvote this answer, let alone vote to delete it, but I am quite disgusted that my answer, which was essentially the same, was downvoted and then deleted.

@DavidHammen The main difference between mine and yours is that mine is an answer to the question asked. And when it wasn't, guess what, it was being downvoted and VTDed also.
